# how to write test class for this class

Tags: apex, unit-test, flow

Please see the class below:

```
global class UpdateSiteStatus {

@InvocableMethod(label='Update Site ' description= 'return the status')



public static list<Siteoutput> UpdateSendStatus(list<SiteInput> SiteIn){
         JSONParser parser;


         Http h = new Http();

         Map<id,Asset> AssetUpdateMap=new Map<id,Asset>();
         Map<id,Asset> AssetMap=new Map<id,Asset>();
         Map<id,Asset> AssetMapUpdate=new Map<id,Asset>();
        list<Log__c> ListLog=new list<Log__c>();
         list<User> currentuser=[Select Id,Name,Email from User where Id=:userinfo.getuserId()];
         List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails =  new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
         string ssiteid,Stitetstatus;


             ssiteid=SiteIn[0].Siteid;
             Stitetstatus=SiteIn[0].SiteStatus;


           list<Siteoutput> Outputlist=new list<Siteoutput>();

           HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
           req.setMethod('POST');
           req.setHeader('Content-Length', '512'); 
           req.setEndpoint(Label.Multisite_Endpoint);
           req.setBody('Email='+Userinfo.getUserEmail()+'&Siteid='+ssiteid+'&key='+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(Label.Multisite_key))+'&Status='+Stitetstatus);
           req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');  
           HttpResponse res;


        if(Test.isrunningTest()==false){
               res = h.send(req);
               parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
                System.debug('=======res ====='+res.getBody());
                System.debug('=======EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(Label.Multisite_key))====='+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(Label.Multisite_key)));
        }else{

         parser = JSON.createParser('{"status":"ok","response":"Site Not Exist!"}');
        }
        try{
           while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
                      if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME && parser.getText()=='response'){
                            parser.nextToken();
                            if(parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.VALUE_STRING){
                                if(parser.getText()<>'Site Enabled!' && parser.getText()<>'Site Disabled!'){

                                  String body='';
                                      Siteoutput stp=new Siteoutput(); 
                                             if(Stitetstatus=='Active')
                                                  body=body+'Site id '+ssiteid+' cannot be Enable as '+parser.getText();
                                            else
                                                  body=body+'Site id '+ssiteid+' cannot be Disable as '+parser.getText();
                                        stp.ResponseMessage=Body;
                                        stp.Response='Error';
                                        Outputlist.add(stp);



                                } else{
                                      String body='';
                                       Siteoutput stp=new Siteoutput(); 
                                          if(Stitetstatus=='Active')
                                                  body=body+'Site id '+ssiteid+' Successfully Enabled ';
                                            else
                                                  body=body+'Site id '+ssiteid+' Successfully Disabled ';
                                        stp.ResponseMessage=Body;
                                        stp.Response='Ok';
                                        Outputlist.add(stp);
                                } 
                            }

                       }
            }
            }catch(Exception e){
             String body='';
                      Siteoutput stp=new Siteoutput(); 
                             if(Stitetstatus=='Active')
                                                  body=body+'Site id '+ssiteid+' cannot be Enable ';
                                            else
                                                  body=body+'Site id '+ssiteid+' cannot be Disable ';

                           stp.ResponseMessage=Body;
                                        stp.Response='Error';
                                        Outputlist.add(stp);
            }


  return Outputlist; 

} 
 global class SiteInput{
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
     public String Siteid;

    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
     public String SiteStatus;


}

 global class Siteoutput{


    @InvocableVariable()
     public String Response;

    @InvocableVariable()
     public String ResponseMessage;
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to write a test class for it? Which line did you have trouble getting the coverage on?

Comment: @istest(SeeAllData=true)
public class Test_updatesitestatus{

 


        static public testmethod void DomainApiExt () {
         test.StartTest();
         
         UpdateSiteStatus obj = new UpdateSiteStatus();
            
         UpdateSiteStatus.SiteInput sitevar=new UpdateSiteStatus.SiteInput();
            
         sitevar.Siteid='site3';
         sitevar.SiteStatus='Active';
            
            
            
         //obj.UpdateSendStatus(sitevar);
         
         
         test.StopTest();
        
    
    }
  
   
}




i trying to write , above  is the code m writing

Comment: it gives me error when i open comment calling list method
Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [UpdateSiteStatus].UpdateSendStatus(UpdateSiteStatus.SiteInput)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the test code from your comment which you should have posted in the original question:

```
@istest(SeeAllData = true)
public class Test_updatesitestatus {
  static public testmethod void DomainApiExt() {
    test.StartTest();
    UpdateSiteStatus obj = new UpdateSiteStatus();
    UpdateSiteStatus.SiteInput sitevar = new UpdateSiteStatus.SiteInput();
    sitevar.Siteid = 'site3';
    sitevar.SiteStatus = 'Active';
    //obj.UpdateSendStatus(sitevar);
    test.StopTest();
  }
}
```

and the problem is that you are passing in a single `UpdateSiteStatus.SiteInput` rather than a list of them.

This change should avoid that compilation problem:

```
obj.UpdateSendStatus(new List<UpdateSiteStatus.SiteInput>{sitevar});
```

You will also most likely have to mock the web service call that your code makes in your test - Google about that.

And also note that `SeeAllData = true` is best avoided - Google about that too.

Comment: it still says
Compile Error: Static methods cannot be invoked through an object instance: UpdateSendStatus(List<UpdateSiteStatus.SiteInput>)

Comment: worked using 
UpdateSiteStatus.UpdateSendStatus(new List<UpdateSiteStatus.SiteInput>{sitevar});

thanx alot..:)